# URL to S3 file in private bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I've uploaded a file using the SDK to my private S3 bucket.

I can access this file through the S3 UI.

However, I cannot access this file through a direct link.  It gives me some XML that includes "AccessDenied" as a code and message.

It seems reasonable that since I'm authenticated in the browser and am clicking on a direct link to the file from the same browser, that I should be allowed through.  At the very least, I should be directed to a login page.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Please provide some details on your current S3 bucket configuration.

Comment: Your expectations are off.  Being logged into the console has nothing to do with being able to fetch objects directly from S3.  The *only* way to fetch a non-public object from S3 is to provide a signed URL (or Authorization header) to authenticate the request. (Right-click and copy the "download" link to an object from the console to see what this looks like. The console generates.) S3 is not an end-user service -- it has no concept of being accessed by "users" or of your browser being "logged in." S3 does not use cookies or have a concept of sessions.  The behavior you describe is expected.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to right click and capture that link.  Can you provide a screenshot so I can see some context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after working on this for a bit, I discovered the best thing is to simply publish the console URL to the file.

https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/{your bucket}/{your file path}?region={the region of your bucket}&tab=overview

Be mindful to specify the correct region.  If you're forming this programmatically, then use Amazon.RegionEndpoint.SystemName.

If you're not logged in, it will ask you for your login!

No signed URL is necessary.

Thanks to everyone who contributed!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to provide IAM users with a link to access a particular path within a particular bucket, without them being overwhelmed by the whole AWS Console interface. This gets them directly to where they need to be.

Comment: To follow up further, in order to prompt the user to provide credentials with IAM user account (vs root) pre-selected and your account ID pre-populated, you can use a URL in the following format: https://{account_id}.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/s3/?bucket={bucket_name}&prefix={bucket_folder_name}%2f

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 places that you need to make sure are set correctly based on how you want to setup access to the bucket. It will either have public or private access.

The properties tab:

Here you can set what you will use the bucket for.

[image: Bucket properties]

The Permissions tab -> Bucket Policy:

[image]

With this, you can then setup access. I was able to generate a policy with this site:
http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

EDIT:

Mine is working with the settings I have shown. I recommend asking the AWS boards if to get to the bottom of it. You could also try this:

[image: Make Public]

Comment: Thank you, this got me started.

I had to go the extra step of specifying a user.  If I don't and just use "*", then it makes the entire bucket public.

"Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::account-number-without-hyphens:user/username"}

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon, it's still saying that access is denied.

Comment: @CINCHAPPS Is your bucket setup for static web hosting?

Comment: I added static web hosting just in case, but still having the same issue.  It doesn't appear to affect it.

Comment: @CINCHAPPS I added another photo. I recommend the AWS boards though since mine is working just fine.

Comment: I believe your bucket is public, mine is private.

Comment: @CINCHAPPS Items or the entire bucket can be set to public or private. If you need everything private, an authenticated HTTPS request is needed to access an object on the S3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the direct link if you are inside a VPC. You have to :
1- Create a VPC endpoint for Amazon S3.
2- Add a bucket policy that allows access from the VPC endpoint.

All steps are described in the following link : 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-private-connection-no-authentication/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: could you add more information about what things to look for at that link